# sum of aggregate function or a subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @s int;
declare @dt date;
declare @p int;
declare @r int;
declare @t int;
declare @rr int;
declare @day int;

set @s = 7; set @p = 14; set @r = 21; set @t = 28;
set @dt = (SELECT DATEADD(month, -1, '2014-02-11')) 
set @day = (select DAY('2014-02-11'))

SELECT 
   SUM(SUM(((DCC.TOTAL * 35) / 100)) / ROUND((((SUM(dcc.EMI) / 100) + 
       (SUM(dcc.[RepoArrear]) / 100)) / ((dcc.TOTAL * 35) / 100)) * 100, 0))  
FROM 
   [DCRA].[dbo].[DCC]
INNER JOIN 
   [DCRA].[dbo].[FEB14_DCR] ON dcc.REGION = FEB14_DCR.REGION 
WHERE 
   dcc.CIRCLE = 'C1' 
   AND (dcc.CURR_DATE BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-11') 
   AND feb14_DCR.CURR_DATE = @dt 
   AND FEB14_DCR.[CIRCLE] = 'C1'
GROUP BY 
   DCC.TOTAL, DCC.CIRCLE, FEB14_DCR.[RESO]
ORDER BY 
   DCC.CIRCLE
```

This is my query. I want sum of this logic. But I get an error instead:

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: please format your code

Comment: I can see 4 SUM statements in your code. There is plenty of summing going on. Can you be more specific with what you want please?

Comment: i am calculating some value from fix table value and getting some other output.

Comment: i have 4 fix value.i am calculating other values from that static four value.It is complicated .

Answer (score 0):

IM in a good mood, so i have formatted your code for you.

The problem you have is your first line has a SUM(SUM(() which you are not able to do without grouping the inner aggrgate first in a sub query.

SO this is the nicely formatted SQL of your query that is failing.

```
BEGIN 
DECLARE @s int;
DECLARE @dt date;
DECLARE @p int;
DECLARE @r int;
DECLARE @t int;
DECLARE @rr int;
DECLARE @day int;

SET @s=7; SET @p=14; SET @r=21; SET @t=28;

SET @dt=(SELECT DATEADD(month, -1, '2014-02-11'))

SET @day=(select DAY('2014-02-11'))


SELECT 
SUM(SUM(((DCC.TOTAL*35)/100)) **------------------- YOU CANT SUM an Aggregate that hasnt** been grouped yet
    / ROUND((((SUM(dcc.EMI)/100) 
    + (SUM(dcc.[Repo    Arrear])/100)) 
    / ((dcc.TOTAL*35)/100))*100,0))
FROM [DCRA].[dbo].[DCC]
         INNER JOIN 
                [DCRA].[dbo].[FEB14_DCR] 
                    ON dcc.REGION = FEB14_DCR.REGION 
WHERE   dcc.CIRCLE = 'C1' 
    AND 
            (dcc.CURR_DATE BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-11') 
    AND 
            feb14_DCR.CURR_DATE= @dt 
    AND 
            FEB14_DCR.[CIRCLE]= 'C1'
GROUP BY 
             DCC.TOTAL 
            ,DCC.CIRCLE
            ,FEB14_DCR.[RESO]
ORDER BY 
            DCC.CIRCLE 

END
```

The way to fix it is by doing the SUM((DCC.TOTAL*35)/100) first then aggregating again.

```
 BEGIN 
    DECLARE @s int;
    DECLARE @dt date;
    DECLARE @p int;
    DECLARE @r int;
    DECLARE @t int;
    DECLARE @rr int;
    DECLARE @day int;

    SET @s=7; SET @p=14; SET @r=21; SET @t=28;

    SET @dt=(SELECT DATEADD(month, -1, '2014-02-11'))

    SET @day=(select DAY('2014-02-11'))

SELECT SUM(DCCTOTALVAL/NULLIF(DCCEMI,0))
FROM (    
SELECT 
            DCCTOTAL =  SUM((DCC.TOTAL*35)/100),
            DCCEMI =  ROUND(SUM(dcc.EMI)/100 + SUM(dcc.[Repo    Arrear])/100) / ((DCC.TOTAL*35)/100) * 100,1)
    FROM [DCRA].[dbo].[DCC]
             INNER JOIN 
                    [DCRA].[dbo].[FEB14_DCR] 
                        ON dcc.REGION = FEB14_DCR.REGION 
    WHERE   dcc.CIRCLE = 'C1' 
        AND 
                (dcc.CURR_DATE BETWEEN '2014-02-01' AND '2014-02-11') 
        AND 
                feb14_DCR.CURR_DATE= @dt 
        AND 
                FEB14_DCR.[CIRCLE]= 'C1'
    GROUP BY 
                 DCC.TOTAL 
                ,DCC.CIRCLE
                ,FEB14_DCR.[RESO]
    )tab

    END
```

Comment: ill be honest and say, if you had formatted the code from the start, the duplicate SUM() may have been easier to see.. just maybe...

Comment: still it gives error Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Comment: i have edited the select items, as there was some problems with another SUM in there.

Answer (score 0):

You aggregate by a group and then aggregate again. This is possible in some dbms (Oracle for instance), but I am not sure this is possible in SQL Server. To circumvent the issue simply surround your statement with an aggregating one, i.e instead of

```
select sum(avg(somevalue)) from sometable group by someothervalue
```

do

```
select sum(x)
from
(
  select avg(somevalue)) as x from sometable group by someothervalue
)
```

In your example (I removed some parentheses. Hope I didn't make a mistake by doing so):

```
select sum(x)
from
(
  SELECT 
    sum(dcc.TOTAL * 35 / 100)
     /
    round(sum(coalesce(dcc.EMI,0) + coalesce(dcc.[Repo         Arrear],0)) / (dcc.TOTAL * 35 / 100), 0) as x
  from [DCRA].[dbo].[DCC]
  inner join [DCRA].[dbo].[FEB14_DCR] on dcc.REGION=FEB14_DCR.REGION 
  Where dcc.CIRCLE='C1' 
  and dcc.CURR_DATE  BETWEEN '2014-02-01' and '2014-02-11'
  and feb14_DCR.CURR_DATE=@dt and FEB14_DCR.[CIRCLE]='C1'
  GROUP BY DCC.TOTAL ,DCC.CIRCLE,FEB14_DCR.[RESO]
);
```

BTW: I removed your order by clause. You cannot order by something which is not in your final aggregate.